# Comparison of editions of Shas menukad

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

As far as I'm aware, there are at least three editions of the Talmud which are currently available with nikkud in the daf itself (the Steinsaltz/Koren, the Tuvia's Judaica, and the Oz Vehadar). In my past experience learning from the Artscroll shas in a chevruta with a talmid of R' Steinsaltz, I learned that there are multiple ways to vocalise the text. (The Artscroll shas has nikkud, but not in the daf.)

As such, I am wondering how these editions compare based on two criteria: the textual correctness (defined by the censors' emendations and other alternative girsaot) and the grammatical correctness of the vocalisation.

How do these (and other editions of shas menukad) compare based on the above criteria and which edition would be the best recommendation?

Comment: Are you saying that some ways of vocalizing the text are not grammatically correct on purpose? I guess קמפליגי is a classic, but is that what you mean, that they compromise grammar for common pronunciation?

Comment: @Yishai, that's how it was explained to me.

Comment: [Here][01] is a complete set of Gemoro punctuated, missing Bava Kama and Bava Metzia.
I compiled it from Dvar Malchus publications from lubavitch who publish it in name of Steinzaltz.
[01]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1zB0q-3AxgwbGFlMFMtVW81cEk

Comment: http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=856&ArticleID=3022 http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/ViewImage.asp?Image=http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/_uploads/extraimg/049.jpg same text compare it with the barokhoth from the answer. there are variances. as well as shteinsaltz doesnt putting any sign under the reish for either ribbi or rabbi however he sees it

Comment: Note well that the "proper" vocalization is generally unknown for words in Talmud. Most manuscripts are unvocalized, and the vocalized sections even may not reflect the original pronunciation. As such, many modern scholarly works on Talmudic Aramaic---including Sokoloff's dictionaries and Bar Asher-Seigal's grammar--only vocalize sporadically and conservatively.